# How do I return a value without using the return statement?

Tags: python, python-3.4

Today I was browsing programming challenge websites and saw an incredibly easy challenge that stated users should try to solve it using as few characters as possible.

The challenge was to merge two arrays into each other. 
So for example:
`['A','B','C']` and `['D','E','F']` would turn into `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']`

The challenge states the user is required to use this opening code:

```
def mergeArrays(a, b):
```

Which is 20 characters long. Naturally, I thought the simplest and shortest way to return the answer would be to use the straight-forward: `return a+b`

Resulting in the complete code of:

```
def mergeArrays(a, b):
    return a+b
```

A total of 29 characters. However, I noticed many people solved it in less characters. Some even in as few as 24 characters. Just 4 characters longer than the required starting code. How does one return a value in fewer characters than return? Can anyone explain how anyone has shortened this answer?

Comment: Try asking on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com -- they specialize in this sort of thing.

Comment: @YuHao It still needs to return something, that would result in "None" being returned, similar if you were to type anything with correct syntax such as 1+1.

Comment: @Paul I'll post there now, thanks!

Comment: Does the question say you have to 'return' the answer?  Because if not, YuHao has it right -- it would merge the two arrays, but it would do it by mutating one of them.  Whoops -- his comment went missing.  I think it was `def mergeArrays(a, b):a+=b`

Comment: @PatrickMaupin I am sure it must be returned, yes. I tried YuHao's answer to be safe and ran into the problem I described in the above comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This challenge](https://codefights.com/challenge/pourgr937AJ9B9zK2) has no limit that you have to define the function yourself. The 24 characters solution is:

```
mergeArrays = list.__add__
```

Comment: Ah, that's it! Thank you, I mistook the starting code as required when only "mergeArrays" was required. I feel silly now, much appreciation.

Comment: @PatrickMaupin In this challenge site,  spaces are not included when counting characters.

Answer (score 0):

While you could get it shorter if you used a 1-letter function name, that's just about as short as it's going to get in Python, without writing your own C extension or overwriting your variables.

If you want to solve it in something shorter, consider another language.  With Ruby, you can get it in 23 characters since there's an implicit return:

```
def m(a, b)
    a + b
end
```

There's other languages like [Golfscript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/) that can accomplish the same thing.  Or you could get into the esoterics with [J](http://www.jsoftware.com/).

Comment: Here is the link to the problem: https://codefights.com/challenge/pourgr937AJ9B9zK2 as you can see, many people have solved it using less characters in Python. There has to be a way.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'm not sure how that clarifies anything.

Comment: I accidentally hit enter too early. You can see the solutions tab with the amount of characters other people used in each language. It is proof that you can solve it in less characters on Python was what I was trying to show.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can use lambda functions for this special case.

```
res = lambda a,b : a+b
```

Comment: No, that's about equal length.  Doesn't make it any shorter.

Comment: Also, you cannot do `return` within `lambda` , just do - `res = lambda a,b: a+b` .

Comment: Yep that was a typo. Oops!